# tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".52674064

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to run a Tkinter GUI on Python 3.x and When I use the .get command to get the number off a scale, this error pops up

`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Downloads\Space RPG. Alpha 0.2 (2) (1).py", line 39, in close
    print (w1.get(), w2.get())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2840, in get
    value = self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".52674064"`

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually means that you're trying to call a method on a widget that has been destroyed. The string `.52674064` is the internal name of a specific widget.

This can easily happen if you call a function via a binding or via `after`, if the widget is destroyed before the binding or `after` call has been triggered.